# How to open a file in C

Tags: c, file-io, fopen

I'm trying make a program to create a .dat file, read the file and call a function to print the data on the screen using one of the following methods: bubble, select or insert, ordering the data by DESC form.
 Anybody can help me? You can see my piece of code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE *arquivo = fopen("teste.dat", "r");

  // testa se o arquivo foi aberto com sucesso
  if(arquivo != NULL)
    printf("Arquivo foi aberto com sucesso.");
  else
    printf("Nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo.");

  printf("\n\n");
  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: And your problem is...?  I see you open a file, never read anything from it, never close it, and then exit.

Comment: I guess he gets an invalid pointer

Comment: @Letícia:Read about f*() family functions. `fwrite()`,`fputs()`,`fread()` etc. And don't forget to call `fclose()` after use it.

Answer (score 3):

Does the file aready exist? If not you have to use "a+" or "w+" as u need for access as second argument. Read the docs http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/ ...

Answer (score 0):

Look your code seems pretty good except it has a very small bug.

Just change that "r" in `fopen` to "a+"

By the "a+" a file is opened from it's very end and then the file can be read and wrote but if not there then it will automatically create it.

If you want to inform the user if a file is not present, use both "r+" and "w+"

But to go on top to the front, you can use `fseek` and `fsetpos` here.